# Repairing my initframs in dracut emergency mode Fedora26

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, initramfs-tools, dracut

I am trying to install Nvidia drivers on Fedora, following [this tutorial](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/).

Everything went fine till 2.7 : reboot to runlevel 3.

While booting I get such warnings :
`dracut-initqueue timeout -starting timeout scripts`

Finally, it starts the **dracut emergency shell**. And suggests to regenerate my initramfs.

The error report says that

```
/dev/fedora/root does not exist
/dev/fedora/swap does not exist
/dev/mapper/fedora_host-004-root does not exist
```

I tried to do `dracut --regenerate-all --force` but the `dracut` command is unknown.

Do you have an idea of how I could regenerate the `initramfs` or fix what I did?

Thank you!

Comment: Not an answer, but a heads-up:  When the tutorial tells you to type “$(uname -r)”, it means that you should type ```$(uname -r)```, not your username.